# Regex capture only 1 space except when surrounded by specific pattern

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm having troubles writing a regex that captures one space but not when surrounded by hex characters and starting with a escaping `\`:

I should capture in these following lines :

```
.c ber
.cb ber
.test test
.\fc ker
.k ker
```

but not here :

```
.bob\fc ber
.\fc ber
```

Currently I came up with `((?<!(\\[\da-f][\da-f])) )` but this one does not handle the part where I need to capture the space not followed by a hex character.

I also tried `(?<!\\[\da-f][\da-f]) (?![\da-f])` but this one does not match spaces that are followed by hex chars but are not preceded by hex chars.

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/HxAjqT/1)

Comment: Can you explain why `.\fc ker` should match but `.\fc ber` not?

Comment: `b` is a hex char while `k` is not. I want to exclude when there is a hex before and after. If it's just after, it's fine.

Comment: I see, so the backslash is only a requirement before... try e.g. [`(?<!\\[a-f\d]{2}(?=.[a-f\d]))( )`](https://regex101.com/r/1Jz4Uu/1)

Comment: Is the length of a hex character indefinite? If so, lookaround would be impossible.

Comment: I need to check the 2 chars before the space and only the first after !

Comment: Here's an alternative that doesn't use lookbehind (in case it's unsupported for your application): `^(?!.*\\.*[\da-f]{2} [\da-f]).*( ).*`

Comment: I thin this is what you want
(?<!\\)(?:(?!\\)(?<![\da-f])) (?![\da-f])

Comment: Why are `.c ber` and `.cb ber` not a space "surrounded by hex chars"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To let a look*ahead* only succeed if the negative look*behind* succeeds, it needs to be inside.

```
(?<!\\[a-f\d]{2}(?=.[a-f\d]))( )
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1Jz4Uu/2)

The lookbehind checks if not preceded by two hex characters and a backslash containing a lookahead to only disallow if one character after the next is a hex character.

Comment: Actually, how would you write it if the negative lookbehind were to be of variable lenght ? (for example with `\\+`)

Comment: I meant, if the `\\` needs to be actually a variable count of backslashes, making the negative lookbehind variable length, which doesn't work !

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler For something like [`(?<!(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)*)\+`](https://regex101.com/r/4QcqS3/1) you need a regex flavor that supports variable length lookbehind (e.g. JS v8, .net regex)